# In Julia: initialize fields with nothing

Tags: julia

I have a `mutable struct` with optional fields like this:

```
mutable struct MyStruct
    field1::Union{Int, Nothing}
    field2::Union{String, Nothing}
    field3::Union{Int, Nothing}
    field4::Union{String, Nothing}
    # ...
end
```

I can now write a default constructor which initializes the fields with `nothing`:

```
MyStruct() = MyStruct(nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing)
```

This is not so nice when my struct has many fields. Also, I have to count the fields to get the constructor call with all the 'nothings' correct in this case. Is there a better way to do that?

Depending on the field content, I want to call different functions later:

```
if mystruct.field1 == nothing
  do_this()
else
  do_that()
end
```

Comment: I'm interested in the use case, but I'd also like to point out that last example is better suited to using parametric functions, ie `f(::Nothing) = ...#something ; f(_) = ... #other thing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fieldcount`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.fieldcount) function to achieve that. This function gives you the number of fields of that an instance of given type would have. Here is an example containing a `mutable struct` and an outer constructor.

```
julia> mutable struct Foo
           x
           y
           z
       end

julia> Foo() = Foo(ntuple(x->nothing, fieldcount(Foo))...); # you can also fill an array and use `...`

julia> Foo()
Foo(nothing, nothing, nothing)
```